# MacOS - How to click key repeatedly when holding it down

Tags: macos

I want to create a keyboard macro that will repeatedly press a key when I hold down on it.

E.g. When I hold down the spacebar, it will repeatedly click the spacebar every 0.5 seconds, instead of simply holding it down.

What software should I use to achieve this?

I am on Big Sur 11.4

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable keyboard repeat on a Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/363252/how-to-enable-keyboard-repeat-on-a-mac)

Comment: @Tetsujin No it does not

Comment: because… ? What about it didn't work?

Comment: @Tetsujin I want to create a keyboard macro that lets me click a key repeatedly at a certain rate (e.g. 0.5 seconds or 0.25 seconds) when I hold down a key. The answer to that question is changing a system setting for typing

Comment: …which is precisely what that setting will let you do. [The opposite is to spring the 'character chooser']. Repeat rate is in keyboard prefs. Software recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: @Tetsujin Ok sorry if my question is off-topic but the answer in that question does not do what I want to do.

For reference I want to use this macro for a game so it will let me repeat an action in the game simply by holding down a key instead of spam clicking it. I tested out the answer you recommended and holding down the key does not repeat the action in the game. 

It seems like that setting is for typing purposes only, so that holding down a key will input the key repeatedly instead of coming up with a prompt for an accented version of the key.

Comment: Games are often programmed to not let you do that. They register the actual key-down & key-up events, which is not quite the same thing as telling a script to emulate a keypress. That it's for a game is therefore a vital component to your question which you failed to mention.